# Mysql Add DATE_COLUMN 3 DAYS with query

Tags: mysql

I've been asking many question here, but it was dead end, I just want to make a simple select from date_column+3 day, I'm new to MySQL.

I've tried with this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM pemesanan 
WHERE pemesanan.`date` = DATE(DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 3 DAY))
```

but the result is empty, here's my column

```
    date
    2016-08-10
    2016-08-04
    2016-08-07
```

it must be show the 2016-08-10 data, but its not,

Can somebody enlighten me, I've been frustrated with this

Comment: you're doing "somefield = somefield + 3 days". a field cannot have a date that's both "today" and "3 days from now". you're getting exactly what you asked for: the result of an impossible condition - no rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use date right side  you should use date left side

```
  SELECT * 
  from pemesanan 
  where  date(pemesanan.`date`) = DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY))
```

If you use the same date  `pemesanan.date`  you never get   `pemesanan.date` =  `pemesanan.date` +3

but if you want select the date older than 3 day you shuold use

```
  SELECT * 
  from pemesanan 
  where  date(pemesanan.`date`) <= DATE(DATE_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY))
```

and for delete

```
  DELETE from pemesanan 
  where  date(pemesanan.`date`) <= DATE(DATE_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY))
```

in your case

```
  SELECT * 
  from pemesanan 
  where  date(pemesanan.tanggal)  <= DATE(DATE_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY))
```

Comment: its show empty, :( idk why, but the query were succed running :(

Comment: if i using now() would it be same result if i run the query tommorow? because i wanna use it for mysql "EVENT"

Comment: i wanna create event that delete record older than 3 day

Comment: If you use now you check for the date that are 3 day form the moment you execute the query .. eg:  if you  execute the query tomorrow (2016-08-08) you match the  pemesanan.`date` = 2016-08-11.. .

Comment: yeah, if i want to use this as query in my SQL EVENT, how can i do like this,  delete from pemesanan where pemesanan.date= pemesanan.date+3 day, so the event would not screwed. thanks

Comment: If you don't want execute  the delete  you can use  DELETE from pemesanan 
  where  date(pemesanan.`date`)  = DATE(DATE_add(date(pemesanan.`date`) , INTERVAL 3 DAY)).   Or you can use also  DELETE from pemesanan 
  where  1 =2 .   (never)

Comment: yeah the last one is im looking for, but its show error You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: where date(pemesanan.date) = DATE(DATE_add(date(pemesanan.date) , INTERVAL 3 DAY))

Comment: where date(pemesanan.date) = DATE(DATE_add(pemesanan.date , INTERVAL 3 DAY) )

Comment: select * from pemesanan where date(pemesanan.`tanggal`) = DATE(DATE_ADD(pemesanan.`tanggal` , INTERVAL 3 DAY) ) it show empty result though, i give up dude, this frustating me :(

Comment: @themasmul   where date(pemesanan.tanggal) = DATE(DATE_ADD(pemesanan.tanggal , INTERVAL 3 DAY) )   don't match anyrows because anyrows  is   true when  pemesanan.tanggal = pemesanan.tanggal +3  ... for this you obatin empty result .. the query is sintactilly right but any rows match the where condition ..  .. anyway i have update the answer with a select that for me should work